# getting public_content permission for instagram, it says "applications no longer accepted"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I want to create an app that can let users login and give basic, follower list and public_content permission. The purpose is to get a users basic info along with public info of non authenticated users. The developer website says:

"public_content - to read any public profile info and media on a user’s behalf (applications no longer accepted)"
"follower_list - to read the list of followers and followed-by users (applications no longer accepted)"

I have a valid use case and did manage to get a successful review approval on facebook.

Looking forward to a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: follower list? what permission would that be? afaik you cannot access the followers. also, of course you cannot get any info (no matter if public or not) about non authenticated users. this has not changed in the last few years. what developer website says stuff like that? not the official one, i assume? please share a screenshot of your login review page in the app settings.

Comment: On the Instagram it says `follower_list - to read the list of followers and followed-by users (applications no longer accepted)` How can you get approval for that scope? I need to get the list of followers of an Instagram user. Looking at the new FB Instagram Graph API I don't see any endpoint I can use to retrieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram stopped giving permission other than basic_profile, so you won't get permission for release and can use only in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Now Instagram is not giving Access to details other than basic.

I was using this API-
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&count={number}
But not able to fetch details of users since 20th Mar 2018.

You can review permissions here-
https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/